# The von Neumann series for time-dependent perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory, time-evolution

i'm currently trying to understand the derivation of Fermi's Golden Rule as outlined in Schwabel's book "Quantum mechanics". When integrating the Schrödinger Equation, the "von Neumann" series appears, which I'm unfortunately not familiar with. It is said that the state ket (in the interaction picture) at time $t$ can be written as

[image]

Which is supposed to be a solution to this equation

[image]

How to get to this expression?

Comment: consider typesetting using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/550071) in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Start with
$$
\vert\psi;t\rangle_I = \vert \psi,t_0\rangle
+\frac{1}{i\hbar}\int_{t_0}^{t} dt' V_I(t') \vert\psi,t'\rangle_I \tag{1}
$$

and use (1) with $t\to t'$ on the left and $t'\to t^{\prime\prime}$ on the right to feed back into itself on the right:
$$
\vert\psi;t\rangle_I = \vert\psi,t_0\rangle_I
+\frac{1}{i\hbar}\int_{t_0}^{t} dt' V_I(t') 
\left[\vert\psi,t_0\rangle_I
+\frac{1}{i\hbar}\int_{t_0}^{t'} dt^{\prime\prime} V_I(t^{\prime\prime}) \vert\psi,t^{\prime\prime}\rangle_I\right]
$$
and then feed (1) again for $\vert\psi,t^{\prime\prime}\rangle_I$ and so forth recursively to get something of the form
$$
\vert\psi;t\rangle_I= \left(
\hat 1 + \frac{1}{i\hbar}\int_{t_0}^{t} dt' V_I(t') 
+\left(\frac{1}{i\hbar}\right)^2
\int_{t_0}^{t} \int_{t_0}^{t'} dt^{\prime\prime} dt' V_I(t')  V_I(t^{\prime\prime})  +\ldots \right)\vert\psi,t_0\rangle_I\, .
$$
The only piece that's missing are the conditions
$$
\begin{array}{l}
0 \le t' \le t\\
 0\le t^{\prime\prime}\le t' \\
\text{etc}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You are solving the evolution operator $U(t,t_0)$ that gives you $|\psi,t\rangle= U(t,t_0)|\psi,t_0)\rangle$ from
$$
i \partial_t U(t,t_0) = V(t) U(t,t_0)
$$
Use   $U(t_0,t_0) ={\mathbb I}$, to rewrite this as
$$
U(t,t_0) ={\mathbb I} -i \int_{t_0}^t V(t') U(t',t_0)dt'.\quad ({\star})
$$
But now we can replace the $U(t',t_0)$ by
$$
U(t',t_0)= {\mathbb I}-i \int_{t_0}^{t'} V(t'') U(t'',t_0)dt''
$$
substitute this in $(\star)$ and keep going. This gives you the [Dyson series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series)

Comment: I've updated my original question, maybe I should have made it more clear what the series is supposed to be solution for because unfortunately to me it doesn't seem that your answer is exactly what I was looking for. But it could just be that I don't quite understand it, in this case I'm sorry

Comment: Is that not exactly what I have said?  Just do the same trick. Replace the $|\psi, t'\rangle$ in the integral on the RHS of your new equation by the same formula $|\psi, t'\rangle= |\psi,t_0\rangle+ 1/(i\hbar) \int_0^{t'}v(t'')  |\psi,t_0\rangle dt''$ and keep going.

Comment: Then I didn't understand earlier, sorry for that and thanks for your help!